# mongodb collections are created without any documents in it

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

So my problem is the automatic creation of collections in my productive database meant to contain the temporary data (but logically are never filled with any of this temporary documents). Why is that and how could i avoid this behavior?

For example a more formal explaination, I've got the two databases - and their containing collections

```
productiveDB.coll1
productiveDB.coll2
```

and

```
temporaryDB.col3
temporaryDB.col4
```

but when i start to store data spring automatically creates

```
productiveDB.coll1
productiveDB.coll2
productiveDB.col3
productiveDB.col4
```

For the records: i'm already using the 1.1.1.RELEASE. I created a small testcase where this behavior is replecated: Both Documents (MyDocOne and MyDocTwo) contain an @Indexed annotation on a custom field - they also contain a field of type object. So when i create entity `myDocOne and myDocTwo` - setting `myDocTwo.obj = myDocOne` and persist `myDocTwo` - spring creates a collection `myDocOne` in `template2`... this is a bit confusing - i hope the following code gives a better overview.

```
public static void main(String[] args ) {
    App app = new App();
    ApplicationContextLoader loader = new ApplicationContextLoader();
    loader.load(app, "applicationContext.xml");

    MongoTemplate template1;
    MongoTemplate template2;

    try {
        template1 = new MongoTemplate(new Mongo("localhost"), "tmp1");
        template1.setApplicationContext(loader.getApplicationContext());
        template2 = new MongoTemplate(new Mongo("localhost"), "tmp2");
        template2.setApplicationContext(loader.getApplicationContext());
        MyDocOne one = new MyDocOne("foo", "bar");
        template1.save(one);            
        MyDocTwo two = new MyDocTwo("foo", "baz");
        two.setAny(one);
        template2.save(two);

    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the documents:

```
@Document
public class MyDocOne {

    @Indexed
    String a;
    String b;

    public MyDocOne(String a, String b) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

@Document
public class MyDocTwo {
    @Indexed
    String a;
    String b;
    Object any;

    public MyDocOne(String a, String b) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void setAny(Object any) {
        this.any = any;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible. Collections in MongoDB are created lazily as soon as they are written to and are not automatically removed when they become empty. There are several open JIRA issues for this or behaviour related to it, specifically :

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-610

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3215

You will have to manually clean up empty collections. A periodic pass that scans all databases for empty collections and drops them (optionally only if the collection name is prefixed with a specific string, e.g. "temp") will do the trick though.

Comment: this is not what i actually wanted to know. the collections are created without any document beeing saved in it.

Comment: That's not strictly true. You will perform a write to the collection (index) data, namely by performing an ensureIndex call.